# Run a BitLocker protected Windows 7 installation on VirtualBox from physical drive

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, bitlocker

I have a broken laptop with its hard drive intact. I'll be getting it repaired in a few days but I **must** continue my work possibly uninterrupted, so I chose to run the OS in another working laptop (I can't just transfer documents).

My question is really simple:

Can I create a virtual machine in VirtualBox (under Linux) that uses the **physical** hard drive mentioned above *which is encrypted with BitLocker*? I have the restore key at hand, of course.

I wouldn't like to mount the hard disk as primary hard disk for laptop (and run 7 as primary OS), but that could be the final choice if virtualizing is not an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Officially, Microsoft does not support Bitlocker in a virtual environment, but somebody claims to have gotten it working on a guest in VMware ([source](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/itprovistasecurity/thread/ff0058a8-5375-44de-892c-5f11fa7698a8)).

The tricky bit about your case is that you've got an existing install on an encrypted disk that you want to run as a guest.  I don't know if you can do that without converting it to a virtual disk image, which you'd have to decrypt the drive to do.